# Electron Interference and Entanglement

Tags: electrons, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment

This might be an uninformed question with some wrong assumptions, but does entanglement play into wave function collapse if we fire single electrons through a double slit?

If electrons from the same source are entangled, does this have an impact on the double slit interference pattern?

For example, if we use electrons from different sources, (which would then not be entangled?), would this affect the interference pattern if they were shot one at a time and observed?

Comment: It is always a good idea to read original sources and to perform your own new and more sophisticated experiments. Not Gedankenexperiments (thought experiments) but real one. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/649619/46708

Comment: In general the DSE does not involve entanglement. Even for single or simultaneous photons or electrons.

Answer (score 0):

The double slit experiment wavefunction is the solution of the scattering experiment "electron scattering off two slits a given width a given distance apart".

[This is how the interference is built](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) up one electron at a time.

[image: doubleslit]

I know of no way to build up an entangled beam of electrons , the way of making electron beams by necessity has the electrons incoherent.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-68181-1

Comment: @Wolphramjonny  interesting, thanks. But electrons are not as pliable.

Comment: I didnt realize that!

Comment: @Wolphramjonny think of lasers with all their coherent radiation.